# How do you simulate a realistic file upload time on your local machine using <input type="file"/>?

Tags: apache, file-upload, localhost, mamp

I'm working on a web page with a file upload form that uploads a file via ajax (with the jquery.form plugin and an updating `<progress>` bar). I am using MAMP, and since a file I upload is just being copied from one location on my computer to another, the upload time is too quick to see the progress bar in action, even if the file is huge.

I remember seeing a screencast where the presenter made some change to his local env that slowed down the upload process but the specific screencast escapes me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install [libapache2-mod-bw](http://ivn.cl/2010/01/06/downloads-for-bandwidth-mod/)

Then in your virtualhost config set:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ...
    BandWidthModule On 
    ForceBandWidthModule On
    BandWidth all 80000
</virtualhost>
```

This will set a 80 KB/s limit on uploads.